# Docker running nginx plus jar

Tags: java, nginx, jar, docker, port

I'm trying to run a docker container that contains both a java jar server and nginx in front of it to perform subdomain->port forwarding, and I don't seem to be setting it up correctly.
This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
MAINTAINER somefool
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install nginx
COPY theBigOwlServer.jar /data/server.jar
RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80 8080
CMD java -jar /data/server.jar     
CMD service nginx start            #<--- line AAA
```

The java jar listens on ports 8080 and 8090. When I run this container with -p 80:80 -p 8080:8080, the jar just doesn't seem to start. I don't see any console output from it, and I can't reach it from outside the container with `curl localhost:8080.` I can reach nginx on port 80, but requests that should be forwarding to the jar are coming back with an empty reply.

However, if I comment out line AAA, then the jar starts fine. It generates console output and `curl localhost:8080` reaches it. How can I run nginx and the jar together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker containers are designed for single-process sandboxing, so only take one CMD argument. In this case it's just picking up the last one in the file. If you need to run multiple prorcesses in a container (and sometimes it makes sense to do so) then use something like [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org) to run your commands for you (so your `CMD` would run Supervisor). Then you get goodies like process watchdogs and such thrown in too.

Comment: Yes, Supervisor got it working, thanks. I followed the directions at https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/ to set it up inside Docker.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
ENTRYPOINT sh -c 'service nginx start && java -jar /data/server.jar'
```

I tried this out and it worked for me.